# Reactjs , .map function output variables error

Tags: javascript, mysql, reactjs, array.prototype.map

So I am doing my school project, building an e-commerce website.
I'm using reactjs, express, and mysql.

The thing is I'm setting up my products output render, by using the .map function, I'm using axios to GET the API from mysql. My react showed the products completely by using .map, but when I'm adding it to my cart it had an error when I add the 1st product in my mysql row, but when I add the 2nd product on mysql row it turned out to be correct. So I try to add a 3rd product, and then 1st and 2nd product can't be added to the cart and only the 3rd product (the last row) could.

Please someone help me to solve this, I asked my friends and they didn't know what's wrong because everything seems correct.

here is my code:

```
class Products extends Component {
  state = {
    mappings: []
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get("http://localhost:3210/product").then(x => {
      this.setState({ mappings: x.data });
      console.log(this.state.mappings);
    });
  }
  buynow() {
    axios
      .post(
        "http://localhost:3210/cart",
        // console.log(this.refs.namaprod.value),
        {
          nama_product: this.refs.namaprod.value,
          quantity: this.refs.quantity.value,
          total_harga: this.refs.price.value * this.refs.quantity.value,
          user_id: this.props.id_user,
          status: "@cart",
          product_id: this.refs.idprods.value
        }
      )
      .then(y => {
        alert("added to cart");
      });
  }
  render() {
    const produks = this.state.mappings.map((y, index) => {
      var namaproduk = y.nama_product;
      var descriptions = y.description;
      var stocks = y.stock;
      var price = y.harga;
      var imggbr = y.img_src;
      var id = y.id_product;
      return (
        <div className="col-lg-3">
          <figure className="card card-product">
            <div className="img-wrap">
              <img src={imggbr} />
            </div>
            <figcaption className="info-wrap">
              <h4 className="title">{namaproduk}</h4>
              <p className="desc">{descriptions}</p>
              <div className="rating-wrap">
                <div className="label-rating">
                  only <strong>{stocks}</strong> kicks left
                </div>
                <input
                  className="quantity pull-right"
                  type="number"
                  placeholder="0"
                  ref="quantity"
                  min="0"
                  max={stocks}
                  required
                />

                <input
                  className="text"
                  ref="idprods"
                  type="hidden"
                  value={id}
                />
                <input
                  className="text"
                  ref="namaprod"
                  type="hidden"
                  value={namaproduk}
                />
                <input
                  className="text"
                  ref="price"
                  type="hidden"
                  value={price}
                />
              </div>
            </figcaption>
            <div className="bottom-wrap">
              <i
                className="btn btn-sm btn-primary float-right"
                onClick={() => {
                  this.buynow();
                }}
              >
                Order Now
              </i>
              <div className="price-wrap h5">
                <span className="price-new">${price}</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </figure>
        </div>
      );
    });
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="ProductFolio">
          <center>
            <h2>Featured Products</h2>
          </center>
        </div>
        <div className="row">{produks}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

confusingly the value of the .map only applies to the last array of mysql, it not should be like that..

any advice will be appreciated.
thanks!

Comment: its because you are using the same ref for all the map items, ref for item 1 (three input elements) is same as ref of item 2 and for three, so at the end ref will have the refernece of third items input field. better to use some unique name for ref like: `ref={'idprods' + i}` and pass i to buynow method and use this to access the correct dom element: `this.refs['idprods' + i]`.value

Comment: @MayankShukla thank you sir, I did this way because it was way easier for me..
I use index from my .map function to replace the i and it worked

Answer (score 0):

It isn't best practice to use refs for this. Here's what the react docs say.

> There are a few good use cases for refs:
>
> - Managing focus, text selection, or media playback.
> - Triggering
>     imperative animations.
> - Integrating with third-party DOM libraries.
>
> Avoid using refs for anything that can be done declaratively.
>
> For example, instead of exposing open() and close() methods on a
>   Dialog component, pass an isOpen prop to it.

Instead, use state to get your values. In your `.map` function assign the index of the item to the button click. As this will pass on that value to buynow when the button is clicked and you can use it there.

```
onClick={() => {
  this.buynow.bind(this, index);
}}
```

Now in your buynow function grab the data of the mappings and use each value from the object.

```
buynow(index) {
  const product = this.state. mappings[index];
  axios
    .post(
      "http://localhost:3210/cart",
      // console.log(this.refs.namaprod.value),
      {
        nama_product: product.name,
        quantity: product.quantity,
        total_harga: product.price * product.quantity,
        user_id: this.props.id_user,
        status: "@cart",
        product_id: product.idprods
      }
    )
}
```

**TIP:** when defining functions use camelCasing, for example name functions or variables like buyNow, updateName, etc.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but as for the code you written i really cant use because of the quantity that needs refs to operate... but this code is great, will see if i'll use this in the future.. and thanks for the tip :)